# MySQL Boolean Partial Search

Tags: mysql, search, partial

I've searched a lot and I previously have had something similar working but I can't quite work out why this isn't producing the results I expect.

Say I have 'test6' within name, manufacturer, model or description, I wish to search for 'tes', but using the below query it doesn't return as I expect.

I have also tried 'test' with "AGAINST('test'+ IN BOOLEAN MODE etc.. any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
ALTER TABLE productinfo ADD FULLTEXT(name, manufacturer, model, description);

SELECT id, name,category_id, price, manufacturer, model, shortdescription, 
       description,stockqty,shippingbase,shippingcost, buyitnow,auctionitem, 
       MATCH (name, manufacturer, model, description) 
       AGAINST('tes'* IN BOOLEAN MODE) as  score 
FROM productinfo 
     WHERE MATCH (name, manufacturer, model, description) 
        AGAINST('tes'* IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY score DESC
```

Resolved, Note: after some research it was an asterisk that needed to be after the search term (in this case 'tes') so AGAINST('tes'* IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems you are running into with this query.

1. Fulltext searches require a minimum word length of 4 ([see the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html))
2. Fulltext searches look for whole words only. To match a partial word you need to put the asterisk inside of the quotes `AGAINST('test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` or you can use a regex or [`locate()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)